# How can I instantiate private data members of two base classes by defining a constructor of a derived class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, derived-class, diamond-problem

This is the problem statement:

Design a base class called Student with the foll. 2 fields:- (i) Name (ii) Id. Derive 2 classes
called Sports and Exam from the Student base class. Class Sports has a field called s_grade and
class Exam has a field called e_grade which are integer fields. Derive a class called Results
which inherit from Sports and Exam. This class has a character array or string field to represent
the final result. Also it has a member function called display which can be used to display the
final result. Illustrate the usage of these classes in main.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
    string name;
    int id;

    public:
        Student(string n, int a)    {name = n; id = a;}
        void display()  
        {
            cout<<"Student name: "<<name;
            cout<<"\nStudent I.D.: "<<id;
        }
};

class Sports : public Student
{
    int s_grade;

    public:
        Sports(string n, int a,int s):Student(n,a)  {s_grade = s;}
        void display()  
        {
            cout<<"\nSports grade: "<<s_grade;
        }
};

class Exam: public Student
{
    int e_grade;

    public:
        Exam(string n, int a,int e):Student(n,a)    {e_grade = e;}
        void display()  
        {   
            cout<<"\Exam grade: "<<e_grade;
        }
};

class Results: public Sports, public Exam
{
    string result;

    public:
        Results(string n,int i, int s, int e):Sports(n,i,s):Exam(n,i,e) {}
        void display()
        {
            Student::display();
            Sports::display();
            Exam::display();
        }
};
```

This was my attempt, but this is quite heavily flawed.

Any solutions?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: 1. Pass the String as a const reference. 2. Use initialisation lists. 3. What is the question

Comment: The call to `Student::display();` should not compile, because it is ambiguous: the `Results` class contains *two* instances of `Student` -- one through `Sports` and one through `Exam`.

Comment: @cdhowie I used a virtual inheritance to inherit `Student` now. It still doesn't compile. What should I do?

Comment: Just so you know, this is *horrible* API design. Please tell your teacher to stop teaching bad habits.

Comment: @EdHeal I got it! I used an initialization list and virtually inherited the base class. No errors! Thank you, and cheers!

Comment: @o11c I know. My teacher is very, very bad when it comes to teaching. **stackoverflow** FTW though.

Comment: @SuyashShetty - Use also const and pass by reference

Answer (score 3):

Student class must be virtual. Other wise there will be two copy's of student members in result. That will lead to an ambiguity.

Comment: +1 even though it is answered in the comments. You need the reputation

Comment: Classes can't be virtual -- I assume you mean that the Student class must be *inherited virtually*.

Comment: Yeah I mean that cdhowie. Here in India teacher's teach us that in hybrid inheritance the base classes must me virtual.

Answer (score 1):

You should use virtual inheritance when deriving Sports and Exam from class Student. This will ensure that only one Student instance will be created for a Results object.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
    string name;
    int id;

    public:
        Student(string n, int a)    {name = n; id = a;}
        void display()  
        {
            cout<<"Student name: "<<name;
            cout<<"\nStudent I.D.: "<<id;
        }
};

class Sports : virtual public Student
{
    int s_grade;

    public:
        Sports(string n, int a,int s):Student(n,a)  {s_grade = s;}
        void display()  
        {
            cout<<"\nSports grade: "<<s_grade;
        }
};

class Exam: virtual public Student
{
    int e_grade;

    public:
        Exam(string n, int a,int e):Student(n,a)    {e_grade = e;}
        void display()  
        {   
            cout<<"\Exam grade: "<<e_grade;
        }
};

class Results: public Sports, public Exam
{
    string result;

    public:
        Results(string n,int i, int s, int e):Sports(n,i,s):Exam(n,i,e) {}
        void display()
        {
            Student::display();
            Sports::display();
            Exam::display();
        }
};
```